# How do I get Bin Path?

Tags: c#, .net

I need to the the bin path of the executing assembly.
How do you get it?
I have a folder Plugins in the Bin/Debug  and I need to get the location

Comment: Why do you need this? Why doesn't the application already have the path, it seemed to find the assembly just fine? What does your deployment look like?

Answer (score 144, accepted):

Here is how you get the execution path of the application:

```
var path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName( 
      System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase);
```

MSDN has a full reference on [how to determine the Executing Application's Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.getexecutingassembly).

Note that the value in `path` will be in the form of `file:\c:\path\to\bin\folder`, so before using the path you may need to strip the `file:\` off the front. E.g.:

```
path = path.Substring(6);
```

Comment: Hi,thanks for your prompt reply. Why is it that if I hardcode the path it finds it and if I do the following code it doesnt .
The only difference I can see is the "\\" .
Am I missing something?

      var binpath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase);
         var fullpath = Path.Combine(binpath, folderName);
         if (!Directory.Exists(fullpath)) return;

Comment: In my case the problem was that the System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName() returns a path with a "file:\\" at the beginning. I just removed it from the string and everything worked.

Comment: This seems to go to the out directory

Comment: *path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName( 
     System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase );*


this worked for me

Comment: I suggest using .Replace("file:\\", "") to remove the file prefix, as it's more specific to the problem.

Comment: This is way more complex when you can use System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory or even System.Environment.CurrentDirectory look up for more info https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.basedirectory?view=net-8.0

Answer (score 81):

You could do this

```
    Assembly asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    string path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(asm.Location);
```

Comment: Or this! `System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)`

Comment: Doesn't seem to work if you're running an NUnit test. The path in that case points to the TEMP directory.

Comment: Don't you want the entry assembly?

Comment: Doesn't work when IIS is shadow copying your dlls

Answer (score 47):

This is what I used to accomplish to this:

```
System.IO.Path.Combine(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.RelativeSearchPath ?? "");
```

Comment: This worked perfect in IIS hosting and Winform, thank you.

Comment: Thanks!
This seems to work work for ASP.NET app and console app. In asp.net `RelativeSearchPath` contains actual "bin" folder and in console app this is `null` and `BaseDirectory` contains actual "bin" path.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer here ! This is how it should done

Answer (score 9):

```
var assemblyPath = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase;
```

Comment: This one is already obsolete

Answer (score 8):

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath)
```

eg. value:

```
C:\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\bin\Debug
```

Comment: Note: This solution is for Windows.Forms only

Comment: Use System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory instead! as answer shows above

Answer (score 3):

```
var path = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase)?.Replace("file:\\", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

`Application.StartupPath`

This is how you can access the bin / debug path

Answer (score 0):

```
string parentDirName = new FileInfo(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory).Directory.Parent.FullName;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: `parentDirNaem` gives the name of Parent Directory, not the Bin path. Please [edit] your answer.