# BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies equivalent for non-web applications

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, winforms, wcf, asp.net-web-api

Compared to `AppDomain.GetAssemblies()`, `BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies()` ([System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.compilation.buildmanager.aspx)) seems a more reliable way to get the assemblies that are referenced by an ASP.NET application at runtime, since [AppDomain.GetAssemblies()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.getassemblies.aspx) only gets "the assemblies that have *already* been loaded into the execution context of this application domain".

Iterating through all assemblies is an important tool for dynamically registering types at application start-up in your DI container and especially during application start-up, chances are that other assemblies are not loaded (where not needed) yet, and the composition root is the first one that needs them. It is therefore very important to have a reliable method to get the application's referenced assemblies.

Although `BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies()` is a reliable method for ASP.NET applications, I'm wondering: **what alternatives are available for other types of applications**, such as desktop applications, windows services and self-hosted WCF services?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The only way I currently see is pre-fetching all referenced assemblies manually, just as the `BuildManager` does under the covers:

```
var assemblies =
    from file in Directory.GetFiles(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory)
    where Path.GetExtension(file) == ".dll"
    select Assembly.LoadFrom(file);
```

Comment: This may have worked at some point but as of now, I had multiple solutions calling this code from various assemblies it would not pick up all my "project DLLs" despite being done properly. I had to supplement said code using this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57258916/3997521.

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same problem. And after doing some research I've still not found a solid answer. The best I've come up with is to combine `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` with the `AppDomain.AssemblyLoad` event.

In that way I can process all already loaded assemblies while getting notified for all new assemblies (which I then scan).

Comment: Unfortunately `AssemblyLoad` won't work, since it will get triggered after assembly gets loaded, while the problem is that assemblies aren't pre-fetched. I'm searching for a built-in mechanism that pre-fetches assemblies, just as the `BuildManager` does. But perhaps there isn't anything built-in to the .NET framework. (but +1 for the trouble)

Comment: Not that I've discovered no. In that case you'll have to load all assemblies from the application folder manually.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is based on @steven's answer. 
But would work in Web, WinForms, Consoles, and Windows Services.

```
var binDirectory = String.IsNullOrEmpty(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.RelativeSearchPath) ? AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory : AppDomain.CurrentDomain.RelativeSearchPath;

var assemblies = from file in Directory.GetFiles(binDirectory)
                 where Path.GetExtension(file) == ".dll"
                 select Assembly.LoadFrom(file);
```