# Simple Injector and assembly scanning

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I'm finally diving into the process of learning about IoC and other patterns and have run into an issue when trying to register open generics based on a list of assemblies. I'm building the core of my framework into separate class libraries and have a set of test projects where I declare some test classes inheriting from my framework.

Problem is that the framework.test.service dll where `AddPersonCommandHandler : ICommandHandler<AddPersonCommand>` isn't loaded at runtime so the `ICommandHandler<>` open generic fails to find anything.  I need to create an `AddPersonCommandHandler` instance in advance then I get one extra assembly in my list and then it works.

Is there a simple way to force loading?

===========
EDIT:
So this is the wireup code in my unit test project which holds the app domain and references to the other assemblies.

```
public Container SetupIoc()
{
    var container = new Container();

    container.Register(typeof(IUnitOfWork), typeof(EntityFrameworkUnitOfWork), Lifestyle.Singleton);

    var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();

    container.Register(typeof(ICommandHandler<>), assemblies);


    container.Verify();

    return container;
}
```

`IUnitOfWork` is in Database.Interface.dll
`ICommandHandler<>` is in Core.dll
`AddPersonCommandHandler` is in Test.Service.dll  -- Part of a suite of projects settings up structure mimicking putting a real solution together and referenced by the Unit Tests.

So, what's happening is that the unit or work registration works fine I think because I'm specifying `UnitOfWork` directly whereas the `ICommandHandler` interface is in the Core which successfully binds.  Post Verify() I only see the unit of work registration on `container`.  To get the Test.Service.dll loading so the `AddPersonCommandHandler` show up I can instantiate an `AddPersonCommand` in my TestInit method.

It just seems a little mad to have to manually load all the dlls for the project.  And for the matter if I scan the executing folder for dlls, some are already loaded...will loading again play nicely or does it require careful checks to find out if it is already loaded?

Comment: Depending on the framework used you have the possibility of text-based configuration to explicitly register/load types, or you can do that manually with `Assembly.Load()` (adding an assembly reference does not make it load at runtime). Right now I'm not sure I fully understand the question though.

Comment: I have seen other resolutions so have done research. What I wanted to know was whether having to scan for the assemblies myself and load them was the only way to do it

Comment: Can you show the code to make the registrations and tell us which platform is used, mvc, wpf, windows service, etc.

Comment: It's just a bunch of class libraries and a unit test project in Visual Studio, .NET 4.6.1 with Simple Injector 3.2.0.  See the edit in my original post for the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to explicitly create an instance of `AddPersonCommandHandler` to make sure the assembly is loaded. All you have to do is reference a type in the assembly (such as your `AddPersonCommandHandler`) statically in code that runs before you call `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()`. For instance:

```
// Load BL assembly
Type type = typeof(AddPersonCommandHandler);

container.Register(typeof(ICommandHandler<>), AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
```

Best is to keep this reference in your Composition Root. This ensures that no matter from where the container is initialized (App_start or integration tests) the same assemblies are loaded.

A more explicit way is to make an explicit list of assemblies that should be used for registration:

```
// Adding the (redundant) namespace of the type makes it very clear to the
// user if this type is still located in the business layer.
Assembly[] businessLayerAssemblies = new[] {
    typeof(MyComp.MyApp.BusinessLayer.AddPersonCommandHandler).Assembly
}

container.Register(typeof(ICommandHandler<>), businessLayerAssemblies);
container.Register(typeof(IQueryHandler<,>), businessLayerAssemblies);
container.Register(typeof(IEventHandler<>), businessLayerAssemblies);
container.Register(typeof(IValidator<>), businessLayerAssemblies);
```

I prefer the latter approach, because this prevents scanning a bulk of assemblies that never contain useful types, while being very explicit about the assemblies (instead of implicitly referencing the type that happens to load its assembly).

Comment: Cool mate.  Whilst it's work I'd rather not have to do I think it's a simple approach.  I appreciate your time.

Comment: @StephenYork Alternatively, you can also do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12781486/264697).

Comment: Yep, I was hoping to avoid that and love option B in you original reply.  Thanks again.