# Programmatically get Folder location for assembly

Tags: c#, .net

[Shadow copying](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/shadow-copy-assemblies) is a feature in the .NET framework to allow assemblies used in an app domain to be updated without unloading the app domain. Very useful in web site binary updates update/release for example.

Is there a programmatic way to read the formal location assembly folder i.e. the website `\bin` folder instead of the shadow copy folder?

For example when `GetExecutingAssembly` like this:

`System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location`

It returns ShadowCopy location folder:
`C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\assembly\dl3\4LPBW244.CR4\DZO34RQG.YAW\caa6207b`

I want to obtain the the `\bin` folder as per my example...

Comment: is this what you are looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/a/3461871/1638261

Answer (score 0):

4 years without a response!
And I needed a response to this exact question!

I finally found a possible answer. This is what I did when trying to obtain the Location of an assembly. The assembly file name was "IKVM.Runtime.DLL"

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad("IKVM.Runtime").Location
```

Note the the file extension had to be removed!